# What are current interest rates on senior/junior/mezzanine loans for e.g. real estate developers?

Tags: interest-rates, banks

For a case study I have to work on for a university course, about a real-estate-development project, I need to simulate the financing with different proportions of equity (40%), senior loan (35%), junior loan (15%) (both from banks), and mezzanine financing (10%) (over 5 years, starting now). I tried to do research, mostly on the net, but did not find any credible sources. Can you give a hint where this can be found (I only need approximate values, to have an estimate)? Is there some national or international index or something similar?

Comment: http://www.inginvestment.com/idc/groups/public/documents/investor_education/fundspace_bswp-senloan.pdf
Here, for example, I found a value of 4.5% for a senior loan (page5), but it does not say anything on the runtime, the conditions, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to this is, unfortunately, not straightforward due to the number of moving parts and no strong reference point.

These types of interest rates can vary highly -- which, during the course of your studies, you will discover is partly a function of the risk-free rate and the risk-premium the project attracts with respect to similar projects. There is also a high degree of variability with respect to the real-estate developer's perceived credit risk.

You can certainly back out much of the data you need using Aswath Damodaran's corporate finance database under the "Updated Data" tab:

http://pages.stern.nyu.edu/~adamodar/

By point of reference, Senior Secureds generally represent 1x Assets or EV. Senior subs about 4-5x and Jnr Subs around 7-8x.

What you really want to find is the spread these products currently have over LIBOR. As you're a student, you should be able to get access to Bloomberg where you can use the `YCRV` function or any of the enormous cap structure / fixed income functions. Likewise via CapitalIQ.

Failing that you could try ValueLine - your school will almost certainly have a subscription - and again back out the implied rates.

As a last ditch attempt, use the implied rates priced into ETFs of corporate bonds of differing grades. BarCap has quite a few of these listed in the US.